# Безопасная работа нескольких серверов с одной БД

Tags: java, sql-server

Есть сервер который работает с БД. У него есть сервис который по таймеру выгребает данные и обновляет их в БД.

Все работает нормально. Но есть команда разработчиков, которые работают с этой тестовой БД. И все могут запустить этот сервис на своей машине. Плюс на тестовой машине он тоже крутится. Ну, по идее, это не делается так, но может возникнуть такая ситуация. Мне нужно придумать, как сделать так, чтобы данные не дублировались.

Например:

- сервис1 вытаскивает 10 строк со статусом 0.
- В это же время работает сервис1 на другой машине, и вытаскивает эти же 10 строк со статусом 0.
- оба ставят им статус 1 и запускают какое то другое событие. То

есть теоретически дважды могут быть запущены какие то события.

Нормальная архитектура подразумевает наличие кучи клиентов и одного сервера, например, который является точкой связи с БД. Но как быть, если несколько серверов сразу могут работать с одной БД?

Comment: Если правильно понял, то это нормальная ситуация, что вас здесь смущает? Есть транзакции, когда один сервис начинает что-то делать, то он начинает транзакцию, выполняет действия, завершает транзакцию. Чаще всего в этот момент другие сервисы, которые обрабатывают эти же данные ждут завершения работы первого сервиса. При этом "ждут" - не вы реализуете, а БД это разруливает, т.е. не выполняет запросы пока транзакция не завершена. При этом возможны взаимоблокировки, тогда вам придется анализировать код и искать решения, чтобы этого избежать. Почитайте, в общем, про транзакции

Comment: я говорю не про два сервиса, а про один и тот же. Два инстанса одинакового сервиса, работают одновременно. и один и тот же сервис делает одно и тоже над одними и теми же строками в БД. Вы не правильно поняли

Comment: я все правильно понял, здесь вообще не важно - одна и та же работа выполняется или нет, база сама это неплохо разруливает (правда, не всегда, про взаимоблокировки я уже писал). Если один инстанс обновляет строки, в которых статус равен 0, то второй будет ждать до тех пор пока первый не закончит работу. После этого он начнет свою работу. Т.е. со стороны можно считать так: работает всего один сервис, он сейчас обновил данные, через некоторое время опять обновил данные, потом еще раз и т.д. А вообще почитайте про масштабирование приложений, тогда не важно будет сколько у вас инстансов

Comment: нет вы не поняли немного. Еще раз. сервис вытаскивает 10 записей, например номерорв телефона, и отправляет на них смски. потом ставит статус 1 и все готово. Теперь представте вытащил он 10 строк и в этот момент второй инстанс тоже вытащил эти же 10 строк, потому что пока первый обрабатывал их он еще не обновил статусы. и в итоге первый отправит 10 смс, и второй отправит 10 смс. да новые строки он не вставит, но работу над ними выполнит дважды

Comment: все я правильно понял, говорю же - почитайте про транзакции. С mssql не работал, но беглый поиск говорит, что там есть `SELECT * FROM tablename WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)` - это (или что-то похожее) вам и необходимо использовать

Comment: спасибо буду гуглить

Comment: Я думаю что само приложение должно решать эту проблему. Для этого уже давно придуманы оптимистичные и пессимистичные блокировки.

Answer (score 3):

Возможные решения:

Для тестового окружения - добавить хинты `WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)` и обернуть все в одну транзацию. Т.е. каждый сервис будет:

1. Открывать транзакцию
2. Выбирать строки на обработку, тем самым ставя лок. Если лок уже стоит - ждать его освобождения.

   ```sql
   select top 1 * from Items WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
   where Status = 'New'
   ```
3. Обрабатывать строки
4. Выставлять новый статус

   ```sql
   update Items set Status = 'Processed' where ItemID = <выбранный в 2>
   ```

Статусы сделаны строками для читабельности.

в этом случае есть небольшая проблема - только один сервис может реально обрабатывать данные в каждый момент. Остальные будут ждать в (2).

Решить это можно убиранием общей транзации и введением дополнительного статуса - `Processing`.

1. Каждый сервис выбирает себе айтемы на обработку, при этом помечая их как Processed (вне общей транзакции, если она есть!)

   ```sql
   update top (1) Items
   set Status = 'Processing'
   output inserted.ItemID, inserted.Status
   where Status = 'New'
   ```
2. Обрабатывает
3. Выставляет им новый статус

   ```sql
   update Items set Status = 'Processed' where ItemID = <выбранный в 2>
   ```

Недостаток этого подхода - при падении приложения или при проблемах с доступом к базе записи так и останутся висеть в Processing. Так что вам придется добавить или обработку ошибок с откатом статуса, или таймаут на нахождение записи в Processing, с откатом в New по его истечению.

Comment: по второму варианту возможна проблема, когда статус "Processing" поставили, но затем возникла какая-либо ошибка и приложение упало не отменив изменения (т.е. не вернув New вместо Processing). Тогда эти строки так и останутся висеть необработанными

Comment: @BOPOH да, такое надо явно обрабатывать в коде. допишу в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Все, что вам нужно - это отдельный сервис блокировок. Когда сервис начинает операцию Х, он блокирует в этом сервисе ресурс Y на небольшое время N, и продлевает блокировку с интервалом N/K секунд. В случае, если серсив отвалился, максимум через N времени блокировка будет снята, и ее можно будет захватить повторно. Такой сервис может быть как реализован внутри той же базы данных, так и использован в виде стороннего готового решения (etcd, consul, redis + redlock).

Блокировка записей сама по себе вас вряд ли спасет, потому что вы работаете не с записями, а с ресурсами, и блокировка записей легко перерастет в нечто монстроузное, конфликтующее и неуправляемое. Хотя нельзя не признать, что блокировка всех обрабатываемых записей однозначно запретит их модификацию, а в случае с блокировкой ответственность за взятие верной блокировки лежит на приложении.